# Finding the original post date

Tags: posts

I somehow used a plugin that changed all the post dates on my blog to the same date.
Is there anyway to find the original post date and change it back?

Comment: Try deactivating the plugin and see if the dates are reverted. If not, I'm afraid the plugin has updated your database and you need to restore a backup, if you have any.

Comment: If you find all posts have actually been updated, are you comfortable coding the solution?  If so, you could loop through posts and restore the original post date from `wp_get_post_revisions()`.  Let me know if you would like sample code for this.